# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3. Issue raise after upgrading gradle version for splunk:mint-android-sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My App was working fine, then I add com.splunk:mint-android-sdk, which required upper version of gradle, so I upgrade the gradle to from 2.1 to 3.3. after that I am facing issues. Please review my gradle file and help me out and please guide me how it work. (This is my first app but I want sure make its should be working fine in all scenario)

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.jar
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom
    https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3/gradle-3.3.jar
Required by:
    :MyApp:unspecified
```

My gradle are

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled= true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "hjaadsffsddd8-2e6hgf-4fdsasdfgb63-8dad5-1111111",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.1,3.99.99]'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'                        
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.2.1'
}
```

and

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.splunk:mint-gradle-android-plugin:5.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: check here about [what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391708/what-is-real-android-studio-gradle-version/51392464#51392464)

Answer (score 31):

Inside buildscript add google() then open terminal write command-- gradlew build and press enter.

[image]

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

NB: Make sure you are in active network connection

Comment: I got this error again `> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2.`

Answer (score 6):

You changed **Gradle plugin** version, not **Gradle** version

Set your **Gradle Plugin** version to 2.3
Then open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change **Gradle** version at line `distributionUrl`

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these steps :

1. Open Your project.
2. Go to the Left side of the Gradle button.
3. [image]
4. Click button above image show .
5. if this type of view you are not in offline mode.
6. Go to Build and rebucild the project.

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This version of the **gradle plugin doesn't exist**.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
```

use the latest beta release:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
```

Instead if you would like to **update gradle**, update the `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti and DeKaNszn 
Finally issue has been resolved with help of your suggestions.
I updated following line of code:
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
and  distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties 'distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip' and MOST IMPORTANT is 
FILE>SETTING>Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradles: Project-level settings: checked :Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)

Comment: @khawarPK I got this error `ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'pluginManagement' for settings 'Saif' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.`

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem removing proxy configuration in file `gradle.properties`

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error, and the problem was the antivirus Avast blocking android studio from download the files.

so I've disabled it temporary and also runned Android studio as an admin. this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` at top of build script.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `gradle wrapper properties` and see if the `gradle version` in the distribution url matches the one in the `build.gradle` classpath's

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I updated following line of

```
code: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

and distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties `'distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/‌​gradle-3.3-all.zip'`

and MOST IMPORTANT is FILE>SETTING>Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradles: Project-level settings: checked :Use default gradle wrapper(recommended)
[image: FILE>SETTING>]

Comment: I got this error `ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'pluginManagement' for settings 'Saif' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.`