# Can't build new project in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I add a new project in android studio but gradle dosen't complete. I get the error

could not find gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2)
searched in the followind locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3. Issue raise after upgrading gradle version for splunk:mint-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316213/errorcould-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-3-issue-raise-after-upgra)

Answer (score 0):

Change your gradle build tool version as below in top level gradle.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

Let me know for more help.

Comment: I changed . but now I get a new error . (could not find aapt-2-proto.jar

Comment: @HasanCheraghi delete old gradle files. Make new project again and then new gradle files will start getting downloaded.